# How to define points with irrational coordinates in SVG?

Tags: svg

Let's say I want to draw a sqare in svg which has a diagonal of 1. That means the edges of the square would have a length of `a = 1/sqrt(2)`. The coordinates of the square's vertices then would be: `(0,0)`, `(0,a)`, `(a,0)` and `(a,a)`. Of course I could approximate `a` with a decimal number and use this number. But what if I want the vertices to be mathematically precise, for example because I want them to be exactly on some line I know to go through the intended point?

I'm totally new to SVG. I was reading up on transformations [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html), hoping to get some pointers, but it got me confused.

Does anyone know if this can be done and if so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SVG doesn't support anything like that.

But you'll get pretty good precision from a floating point approximation. There won't be very many scenarios where you'll see the errors once the SVG is rendered, unless you are magnifying it *a lot*.

If the svg is embedded in web page - and if you are noticing errors under high magnification - you could consider modifying the SVG dynamically with JavaScript, rather than applying SVG transforms.

Answer (score 6):

@PeterHall's answer is correct, and you should accept it. SVG has no feature for this.

Note that each additional decimal place of floating point precision grants you an additional 10x zoom. Suppose a high resolution screen of 2000px wide and a `viewBox` width of only 2. With this unlikely scenario three decimal places are sufficient to uniquely identify each pixel on screen. An additional decimal place gives you 10 degrees of subtle anti-aliasing as the point moves from one pixel to the next. So let's start with 4 decimal places.

At this point you have at least 12 **more** decimal places of precision available with floating point numbers. It seems highly unlikely to me that you will be creating an interactive SVG requiring or allowing zooming in by a factor of 1 *trillion*.

I definitely understand your purist desire. Sadly, SVG does not support it. Happily, the practical, pragmatic alternative offered by SVG should satisfy your needs adequately.

Answer (score 5):

SVG does not support inputs of irrational numbers but that does not mean that it is impossible to have them. Due to the ability to translate and rotate, it is possible to create any [constructible number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number). Because `1/sqrt(2)` *is* constructible, it is possible to do it.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#DDD"/>
 <symbol id="rectangle">
  <path d="M0 0.5 0.5 0 1 0.5 0.5 1" fill="#000"/>
 </symbol>
 <use xlink:href="#rectangle" transform="rotate(45) translate(0, -0.5)"/>
</svg>
```